# Can I use Jasmine functions from a Jest test?

Tags: jestjs, jasmine

I've read that Jest is built on top of Jasmine, so I was assuming I could still call Jasmine functions from a Jest test.

But I'm getting things like "spyOnProperty is not defined" from my Jest test (even though I have Jasmine and Jasmine types defined in the project).

Is this just not possible?

Comment: Note that I am able to call Jasmine "expect" functions from the test.  But not "spyOnProperty".

Comment: Jest provides that: https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname-accesstype

Comment: Right, but I'm still wondering if it is possible to call these Jasmine functions from a Jest test.  If Jest is written on top of Jasmine, shouldn't all the Jasmine functionality be available?

Comment: I think you've answered that question yourself! Note that Jest is moving away from Jasmine generally, Jest Circus will be the default runner soon (see https://jestjs.io/blog/2020/05/05/jest-26) and it's better to rely on the official API if you don't want your tests to break at some point.

Comment: I'm not seeing that I have answered my own question - I'm still a little confused.  In  my test, I can successfully call:
jest.spyOn() and
jasmine.createSpy()

But, if I call these:
jasmine.createSpyObj() or
spyOnProperty()

I get the "ReferenceError: spyOnProperty is not defined".
Why would I be able to call some Jasmine functions and not others?
They are all defined in node_modules/@types/jasmine/ts3.1/index.d.ts
How could some of those work and others not?

Comment: You’ve answered *”is it possible to call these Jasmine functions from a Jest test”* - as your experiment showed, no. The `jasmine` object is there (if you’re using that test runner), so you can access methods on it (but shouldn’t for reasons mentioned above) but not all of the Jasmine globals are exposed by Jest. Use Jasmine *or* use Jest, and don’t depend on implementation details (in general this is good advice)!